# C++ Unexpected behavior with istream, getline, binary file, regex and strings

Tags: c++

I'm working with a file that combines text and binary formats (and sometimes just plain text). So I decided to open the file as binary and give it a try. However, I'm getting unexpected behaviors when I later use regular expressions (the kind of issues that indicate memory corruption):

(Edited to have a minimum example)

```
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <regex>
#include <ios>

struct FortranFormat {
    std::string itemsPerRow;
    std::string type;
    std::string numberOfCharacters;
};

class XXXParserException: virtual public std::runtime_error {
    using runtime_error::runtime_error;
};


std::string parseSection(const std::string &line) {
    return  line.substr(16, std::string::npos );
}


FortranFormat parse(const std::string& expression) {
    const std::regex getItemsExpr("\\(([0-9]+)([A|a|I|i|F|f|E|e])([0-9]+)\\)");

    std::cout << "expression: " << expression << std::endl;

    std::smatch elements;
    if (std::regex_match(expression, elements, getItemsExpr)) {
        
        return {elements[1].str(),elements[2].str(),elements[3].str()};
    } else {
        throw XXXParserException("The expression " + expression + " is not a recognized Fortran Format.");
    }
}

void main() {

    std::ifstream fb;
    fb.open("example.txt", std::ios::binary); // remove the binary flag, and it works
    std::string line;
    getline(fb, line);
    std::cout << "line: " << line << std::endl;
    std::string formula = parseSection(line);
  
    auto format = parse(formula);
    
    std::cout << "format: " << format.type << std::endl;
}
```

The prints have the right information:

```
line: *VALUES        6(5E16.8)
expression: (5E16.8)
```

(Even the exception text is broken and only has the last portion:
" is not a recognized Fortran Format.")

So, more out of curiosity than nothing: Am I doing something fundamentally wrong that is breaking something internally? Is this something that could be attributed to the compiler (VS2015)?

Just FYI, I will try a "jump between formats approach" to solve the issue (save the current position, close and open as text or binary as needed, restore position), but I just want to understand what might be wrong with my current approach.

Comment: Cannot really tell anything without a [mcve].

Comment: A carriage return `\r` at the end of the line perhaps? Debugger will be the best tool to verify.

Comment: Is this on Windows?  Text files need to be opened in text mode there to map newline characters correctly.  Update: just seen you are using VS 2015.  What kind of file is it that contains a mixture of text and binary?

Comment: I'll try to create the minimal reproducible example

Comment: To answer the question: it is an old, in-house format

Comment: @Yksisarvinen. You were right on spot!  I changed the end of lines to unix-EOL and parsing worked.  Always the end of lines with these files. Thanks a lot. Now... I still don't understand why would it trigger an exception, though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two things to consider:

In text mode, `\n` is handled as the native EOL combination (so it would be `\r\n` on Windows). In binary mode no such thing is done, so `\n` is always the newline feed character and nothing else. You ask to read as much text as possible until `\n`, which on Windows leaves you with `\r` at the end of the string.

Then, [`std::regex_match`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/regex/regex_match) requires the whole string to match regex. Your regex doesn't allow for extra whitespace at the end of string, so it doesn't match. [`std::regex_search`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/regex/regex_search) would return `true` on that input, because a substring without the last character matches the pattern.

---

Protip: [Raw string literals](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/string_literal) make regexes much easier, because you don't have to escape literals (easy to debug in regex101 now!):

```
const std::regex getItemsExpr(R"eos(\(([0-9]+)([A|a|I|i|F|f|E|e])([0-9]+)\))eos");
```

Comment: Thanks for the pro-tip. The \r at the end was not caught by the regular expression, not even using .* at the end. But what I did was  to remove the "\r" from the line right when it was acquired and that did the trick.